# Accessing parent elements collection within SUBQUERY NSPredicate

Tags: ios, core-data, subquery, nspredicate

I am trying to use a SUBQUERY within my NSPredicate to traverse a collection within the parent entity of the entity I am searching.

I am searching on the "Product" element, the parent of this is "ProductTitle". I am trying to do a subquery on `product.productTitle.categories`.

```
SUBQUERY(productTitle.categories, $x, $x.name == %@).@count != 0
```

This should return all products whose productTitle parent belongs to a category with the name specified. But I get the following error from core data:

```
CoreData: error: (1) I/O error for database at xxx SQLite error code:1, 'no such column: t4.ZNAME'
```

Am I doing this wrong? Can I use subquery to traverse a collection on the parent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extra information: I have a "categories" collection on the product element too - and when I do a subquery of:
   SUBQUERY(categories, $x, $x.name == %@).@count != 0

it works perfectly fine, but I also need to do the subquery on the productTitle level

Comment: Is `productTitle` a to-one relationship? Then a simple `"ANY productTitle.categories.name == %@"` predicate should work.

Comment: awesome thanks so much that worked! if you add it as an answer I will tick it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "productTitle" is a to-one relationship then you should get the desired result with the following predicate (a SUBQUERY is not needed):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY productTitle.categories.name == %@", selectedName];
```